# Sharepoint 2013 rest api group subtask with respective main task?

Tags: rest, api

Want to display Task and sub-task using the  rest api jquery. My query string displays task and sub-task as individual unrelated task.

Comment: function onQuerySucceeded(data) {
    var mainTasks = [];
    var subTasks = [];
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if(data[i].ParentID.Id) {
        subTasks.push(data[i]);
    } else {
        mainTasks.push(data[i]);
    }
}
        
    $("#divTaskItems").html(mainTasks);

    $("#divSubTaskItems").html(subTasks);
}

function onQueryFailed() {
    console.log('Error!');
}

Comment: above is the code I am using to bind data

Comment: You cannot directly put array variables in html. You need to iterate those array and write each value in html using javascript.

Comment: Check [this](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Bind-JSON-data-to-HTML-Table-using-jQuery.aspx) and [this](https://www.encodedna.com/javascript/populate-json-data-to-html-table-using-javascript.htm) link... How to bind data to html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SharePoint Tasks List, for each subtask there is one hidden field `ParentID` in list. `ParentID` is maintained internally by SharePoint.

So, the list items having ParentID are the subtask. And you can group those subtasks based on ParentID using javascript code. Use below URL to get the ParentID of task items.

```
siteUrl/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('TasksList')/items?$select=*,ParentID/Id&$expand=ParentID
```

and then you can extract the main tasks and subtasks in separate arrays:

```
var mainTasks = [], subTasks = [];
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if(data[i].ParentID.Id) {
        subTasks.push(data[i]);
    } else {
        mainTasks.push(data[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and it did not work, the info would not display on my page.

Comment: Code
<body>
<div id="divTaskItems"></div>

    <div id="divSubTaskItems">/div>
    <p>Get Site List via REST API Call</p>

Comment: function getListData() {
    //var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
    var fullUrl = "myurl/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Tasks')/items?$select=*,ParentID/Id&$expand=ParentID";

    $.ajax({
        url: fullUrl,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: onQuerySucceeded,
        error: onQueryFailed
    });
}

Comment: function onQuerySucceeded(data) {
    var mainTasks = [];
    var subTasks = [];
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if(data[i].ParentID.Id) {
        subTasks.push(data[i]);
    } else {
        mainTasks.push(data[i]);
    }
}
        
    $("#divTaskItems").html(mainTasks);

    $("#divSubTaskItems").html(subTasks);
}

Comment: This code is just to retrieve the list items and find the subtasks. It will not write the tasks on your page automatically. You need to fetch the tasks using this code and then write logic to bind this data on your page.

Comment: Add the code you are using to bind data on page in original question, by editing this question.