# Unable to match a subtasks to its parent tasks REST API

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, tasks

I am able to get the tasks and subtasks from a SharePoint list using the REST API. How can I match a subtask with its parent task? The following JS inside an AngularJS controller returns two lists, subtasks, and maintasks. The subtasks have a ParentID property that shows the id number of the parent. However, the parent does seem to have a property that I can match that id number to.

```
$scope.subtasks = $scope.projects.filter(project => {
    return project.ParentID.Id;
})
console.log($scope.subtasks);

$scope.maintasks = $scope.projects.filter(project => {
    return !project.ParentID.Id;
})
console.log($scope.maintasks);
```

This is one of the returned parent tasks:

```
0:
$$hashKey: "object:3"
AssignedTo: {results: Array(1)}
Assigned_x0020_Team: {__metadata: {…}, results: Array(1)}
DueDate: null
OPR: {__metadata: {…}, results: Array(1)}
ParentID:
__deferred: {uri: ".../_api/Web/Lis…-c959-45d4-a94d-319a5b9dbf80')/Items(21)/ParentID"}
__proto__: Object
PercentComplete: 0
Status: "Not Started"
Title: "FMC Data Degraded In Blue"
__metadata: {id: "Web/Lists(guid'1900342c-c959-45d4-a94d-319a5b9dbf80')/Items(21)", uri: "https://.../_api/Web/Lis…'1900342c-c959-45d4-a94d-319a5b9dbf80')/Items(21)", etag: ""15"", type: "SP.Data.NET_x0020_ProjectListItem"}
__proto__: Object
```

This is one of the returned subtasks:

```
29:
AssignedTo: {results: Array(3)}
Assigned_x0020_Team: {__metadata: {…}, results: Array(1)}
DueDate: "2021-04-29T22:00:00Z"
OPR: {__metadata: {…}, results: Array(2)}
ParentID:
Id: 43
__metadata: {id: "b742ae27-ebf6-4b74-b5ea-0bc75895c590", type: "SP.Data.CNDNET_x0020_ProjectListItem"}
__proto__: Object
PercentComplete: 0
Status: "Not Started"
Title: "Second Circuit"
__metadata: {id: "Web/Lists(guid'1900342c-c959-45d4-a94d-319a5b9dbf80')/Items(104)", uri: "https://.../_api/Web/Lis…1900342c-c959-45d4-a94d-319a5b9dbf80')/Items(104)", etag: ""2"", type: "SP.Data.NET_x0020_ProjectListItem"}
__proto__: Object
length: 30
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the main tasks and subtasks in separate arrays in `success` function like:

```
var mainTasks = [], subTasks = [];
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if(data[i].ParentID.Id) {
        subTasks.push(data[i]);
    } else {
        mainTasks.push(data[i]);
    }
}
```

For more information check this:

1. [Sharepoint 2013 rest api group subtask with respective main task?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/253423/sharepoint-2013-rest-api-group-subtask-with-respective-main-task)
2. [SharePoint 2013 group list task and subtask via the rest api not working](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/253577/sharepoint-2013-group-list-task-and-subtask-via-the-rest-api-not-working)

Comment: How do you know what parents have which children. For example, if a subtask has a ParentID of 32. How can I find that Parent task?

Comment: Also, in your code you end up with two different lists (mainTasks, and subTasks) with no apparent relationship. So, for any task in mainTask how do you know which sub task in subTasks belong to it?

Comment: You can loop these two arrays and match `ID` from `mainTasks` array to `ParentID.Id` from `subTasks` array.

Comment: Ganesh thank you very much for your feedback. However, the mainTasks do not have a ParentID.Id only the subTasks do. So, if there is a subTask with ParentId of 32 there is no way to find the Parent Id that corresponds with 32.

Comment: That's why you have to loop through both arrays and compare `ID` from mainTasks (not ParentID) with `ParentID.Id` in subTasks. `ParentID.Id` from subtask is always equal to the `ID` of it's Parent task.

Comment: Ganesh. Thanks for the solution. I realize now that the Parent task has an ID but I was not pulling that from the list. After pulling in the ID for all the list items I can match the ParentID from subtask to ID from maintasks.

Comment: great, glad it worked for you.